# How to remove segment URL when use Response.Redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Current page URL is: `localhost/Controller1/Index#select_state`
When I call `Response.Redirect("/")`,
new URL is: `localhost#select_state`

How to remove #select_state in new ULR?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Before you are doing `Redirect` operation you have to check whether the database provided url has the valid or not. After you have to use the `response. Redirect` operation. Or try with below code, to achieve your requirement.

```
 dynamicurl = "/";  
url = "localhost//Controller1/Index"  
Response.Redirect(url + dynamicurl);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try redirecting to an absolute URI:

```
Response.Redirect(Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + Request.Url.Host);
```

Comment: thank you! but url `"/"` used in `Response.Redirect("/")` is dymamic, it was read from database.

Comment: @ĐặngTấnNgọc So "/" is actually a variable?  Can you just do `new Uri(new Uri(Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + Request.Url.Host), yourDBVar).ToString()`?